# My tube lose air once inside Tyre and mounted on wheel?

Tags: mountain-bike

I am getting this weird experience.My tube holds the air when removed from wheel and tyre but lose it once in tyre mounted on wheel.I removed it 4 times and checked for bubbles in water bucket.No puncture.Air holds even for days out side wheel and once it is inserted in Tyre ,mounted on wheel and pumped the air,it lose in a min .What could be the reason?Some ghost/spirit playing games?I am really puzzled .

Comment: Pump the tire up to pressure and put the tire in the bucket.  I will bet it is the value.

Comment: Do note that when you inflate a tube outside of the tire it contains 5 psi max.  But inside the tire you inflate anywhere from 30 to 100 psi.  It's easy to have a leak that is insignificant at 5 psi.

Comment: To check the valve, just put some water on it when the tube is pumped up. If the valve is broken or not tighten up you will see bubbles.

Comment: Most people forget you can put water in the bath tub and put the wheel in the bath to see if the tube under real pressure is leaking. Obviously if you don't want to waste a bath full of water, put it in with a friend or loved one ;)

Answer (score 2):

Check the rim for protrusions - is the rim tape misaligned?  Are there any lumps/bumps?  Any spoke ends prodruding just a bit too far?

Check the inside of the tyre/tire for lumps and bumps too.

Are you using a presta valve in a schrader-sized rim hole?  Could be opening a small hole there when pressurising.

Do you always put the tube in the same way around?   Try flipping it to move any weak point around.

Hmm - "weak point"  raises a thought...  Perhaps you should cut your losses and just fit a new tube.  They're consumable; I guess your current one has done its dash.   Don't want the weak point to turn into a blowout.

Answer (score 1):

In normal course ,similar like yours but presently within a min after pumping air.I checked the tube outside the tyre and wheel again by filling more than 15psi air ,as per the suggestion by Daniel R.Hicks and found one recently fixed puncture was leaking. So found the issue and will fix that puncture again .Hope it would solve the issue. There was no leak in valve at approximate 15psi air in tube. Thanks all for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

How fast? It is completely normal that you lose pressure. My road bike goes from ~100psi to ~80psi over the course of a week with its current tubes.